# "detectFASTFeatures" how do you call MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, function

It is an image processing function, but my MATLAB does not have it. I know it must exist because of this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectfastfeatures.html Does anyone know how to import functions or what needs to be done for these things to work?

My MATLAB is 2012b if that helps.

Comment: Use the [author's code](http://www.edwardrosten.com/work/fast.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need the Computer Vision Systems Toolbox. It's not standard to MATLAB, you have to buy it extra.

Answer (score 0):

In my Matlab R2012b, with the Computer Vision Blockset/Toolbox, I don't have this function (and no information available in the offline help section, too).

I looked at the release notes of the blockset (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html) but could not find a mention of the "detectFASTfeatures" launch date. However, it is safe to assume that it was only added in a more recent version.

Hope it helped!